# How to redraw JPanels inside BorderLayout

Tags: java, swing, grid, jpanel, repaint

Inside my borderlayout, i have JPanels which are referenced by the array theGrid. In a separate function, I want to change the look of a JPanel, so I change how the specific JPanel should be painted. The problem im having is that i dont know how i now make it paint this new version of the JPanel?

I have looked at other questions and have tried using .revalidate, .validate, .repaint(), etc on mainPanel or on contentPane, or on both but none will get the new version of the JPanel i created to be drawn on.

In the constructor below I setup the grid and how it will fit into the rest of the JFrame

```
 public class GraphicDisplay extends JFrame {

        private static int ROWS = 6;
        private static int COLS = 7;
        private JPanel[][] theGrid = new JPanel[ROWS][COLS];
        private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(ROWS, COLS));
        private Container contentPane;

        public GraphicDisplay() {
            for (int i = 0; i < theGrid.length; i++) { //Initialize theGrid (with blanks)
                for (int j = 0; j < theGrid[i].length; j++) {
                    theGrid[i][j] = new JPanel();
                }
            }

            //add them to the JFrame
            contentPane = getContentPane();
            contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            JPanel boardElements = new JPanel();
            boardElements.setLayout(new BoxLayout(boardElements, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS)); //vertical layout for the two parts, theGrid itself and then the
            // button which goes underneath, 

            final int SPACE = 3;
            final Color COLORCHOICE = Color.BLACK;


            mainPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(SPACE, SPACE, SPACE, SPACE));
            mainPanel.setBackground(COLORCHOICE);
            JPanel[][] panels = new JPanel[ROWS][COLS];
            for (int i = 0; i < panels.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < panels[i].length; j++) {
                    panels[i][j] = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 1, 1, 1));
                    panels[i][j].setBackground(COLORCHOICE);
                    panels[i][j].setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(SPACE, SPACE, SPACE, SPACE));

                    mainPanel.add(panels[i][j]);


                    panels[i][j].add(theGrid[i][j]);


                }
            }
            //adding the grid to the vertical layout
            boardElements.add(mainPanel);
            //adding the button which will go directly under the grid
            boardElements.add(new JButton("Button"));

            contentPane.add(boardElements, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        }
```

The function below which is in the same class is suppose to update the grid by adding a dot at the point 3,3 (but the problem i don't see any visible change)

```
    public void addDotToGrid() {
                   //theGrid[3][3] reference was added to the panels array which is part of the layout, so I would of thought by changing the value of it here would then change this JPanel on the UI
                    theGrid[3][3] = new JPanel() {
                        public void paintComponent( Graphics g) {
                            //g.setColor(Color.RED);
                            int y = 0;
                            int diameter = getWidth() -10;
                            int x = (getWidth()/2) - (diameter/2);
                            super.paintComponent(g);
                            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
                            // Assume x, y, and diameter are instance variables.
                            Ellipse2D.Double circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, diameter, diameter);
                            g2d.fill(circle);

                        }
                    };


}
```

Main method in another class where GraphicDisplay object is created

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

            GraphicDisplay display2 = new GraphicDisplay();
            display2.setSize(600, 600);
            display2.setVisible(true);
            display2.addDotToGrid();
        }
```

The problem is the grid is displayed but the addDotToGrid() does not change anything and there isn't a dot added to the gird

Comment: The preferred size of a JPanel with no children is 0×0 pixels, plus the insets of its Border if it has one.  Override getPreferredSize() in your JPanel subclass to return a size that accommodates your ellipse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're changing a JPanel held by your theGrid array, but this has no effect on the JPanels displayed in the GUI, and this gets to the key difference between a variable and a reference or object -- changing the object that a variable refers to has no effect on the object that it previously referred to. Your solution is to change the JPanel held by the grid.

One way to do this is to give all of them paintComponent methods that draw what you want, but have them controlled by a boolean, and then change the boolean variable of the panel of interest.

If this were my GUI though, I'd create a grid of JLabels and simply swap ImageIcons where and when I want -- keep it simple as possible!

For example

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MyGridEg extends JPanel {
    private static final int SPACE = 6;
    private static final int ROWS = 6;
    private static final int COLS = 7;
    private static final int IMG_W = 80;
    private static final int SML_GAP = 3;
    private static final Color IMG_BACKG = new Color(240, 240, 240);
    private static final String TITLE = "Click on a Cell";

    private JLabel[][] labelGrid = new JLabel[ROWS][COLS];
    private Icon blankIcon = createIconDisk(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
    private Icon redIcon = createIconDisk(Color.RED);

    public MyGridEg() {
        MyMouse myMouse = new MyMouse();
        JPanel gridHolder = new JPanel(new GridLayout(ROWS, COLS, SPACE, SPACE));
        gridHolder.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        for (int i = 0; i < labelGrid.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < labelGrid[i].length; j++) {
                JLabel label = new JLabel(blankIcon);
                label.addMouseListener(myMouse);
                labelGrid[i][j] = label;
                gridHolder.add(label);
            }
        }
        gridHolder.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, SPACE));

        JLabel titleLabel = new JLabel(TITLE, SwingConstants.CENTER);
        titleLabel.setFont(titleLabel.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 20));

        JButton clearButton = new JButton(new ClearAction("Clear"));
        JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel();
        btnPanel.add(clearButton);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(gridHolder, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        add(titleLabel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    }

    private Icon createIconDisk(Color color) {
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(IMG_W, IMG_W, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2 = img.createGraphics();
        g2.setBackground(IMG_BACKG);
        g2.clearRect(0, 0, IMG_W, IMG_W);
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setColor(color);
        int x = SML_GAP;
        int y = x;
        int width = IMG_W - 2 * x;
        int height = IMG_W - 2 * y;
        g2.fillOval(x, y, width, height);
        g2.dispose();
        return new ImageIcon(img);
    }

    private class MyMouse extends MouseAdapter {
        @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                JLabel selected = (JLabel) e.getSource();
                Icon icon = selected.getIcon() == blankIcon ? redIcon : blankIcon;
                selected.setIcon(icon);
            }
    }

    private class ClearAction extends AbstractAction {
        public ClearAction(String name) {
            super(name);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            for (JLabel[] labelRow : labelGrid) {
                for (JLabel cell : labelRow) {
                    cell.setIcon(blankIcon);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        MyGridEg mainPanel = new MyGridEg();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MyGridEg");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

The key to this code is that I'm not swapping out JLabels or JPanels but rather I'm keeping the JLabels the same, but am changing their state. This way if I change the state of the JLabels held by the 2D array, labelGrid, this is reflected by changes in the view, as I do in the ClearAction class that the clearButton JButton calls:

```
private class ClearAction extends AbstractAction {
    public ClearAction(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        for (JLabel[] labelRow : labelGrid) {
            for (JLabel cell : labelRow) {
                cell.setIcon(blankIcon);
            }
        }
    }
}
```